# Efficient way to search for a string in multi-dimensional list inside Dart Map

Tags: dictionary, search, multidimensional-array, dart

I have a bunch of data stored in the following format (`Map<String, List<List<String>>>`):

```
{
  '<date>': [
    ['<item_1>', '<price_1>'],
    ['<item_2>', '<price_2>'],
    ...
  ],

  '<date>': [
    ['<item_1>', '<price_1>'],
    ['<item_2>', '<price_2>'],
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

If a user searches for a particular item by entering a string, I want to display the list of `item`s with their associated `price` that match (some) part of the string in as efficient and fast way possible, provided that a large number of data in the given format is stored.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any code to show, but a linear search repeatedly of the list data will be expensive.  You should construct an index keyed by the items, with a list value of the one or more prices.  Then as you are trying to autocomplete, find matching keys and their corresponding values.

Comment: But constructing a data structure with `index keyed by the items` out of the existing data would also be expensive. Right?

Comment: Not if the index is used repeatedly.  Sure, it's more expensive if used only once.